# SQL SP with multiple values for an input

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I've inherited a db etc from another developer and need some help.

I have the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TESTgetSearchResults] 
    (
    @ids varchar(100),
    @Date DateTime = Null, 
    @Date2 DATETIME = Null,
    @Sort VARCHAR(5), /* ASC or DESC */
    @SortBy VARCHAR(10), /* Sorting criteria */
    @Location VARCHAR(40)
    )
AS
    SELECT @Date = GetDate()
    SELECT @Date2 = DATEADD(day,-14,GETDATE())    

BEGIN
    SELECT Aircraft.Id AS AircraftID, AircraftManufacturers.Name, AircraftModels.ModelName, 
    Aircraft.ModelSuffix, Aircraft.ImageFileName, Aircraft.Year, Aircraft.SerialNo, 
    Locations.DescriptionForSite, Aircraft.Description, Aircraft.Description2, 
    Aircraft.InfoWebAddress, Aircraft.ImageDescription, Advertisers.Id AS AdvertisersID, 
    Advertisers.Name AS AdvertisersName, Aircraft.AircraftDataId, Aircraft.ForSale, Aircraft.ForLease, 
    Aircraft.TTAF, Aircraft.ReSend, Aircraft.ReSendReason, Aircraft.Registration, Aircraft.AdType,
    Aircraft.HasAlternateImage, Aircraft.AlternateImageDescription, 
    Aircraft.Price, AircraftModels.AircraftType, Advertisers.CurrentEMagLink, Aircraft.CurrentEMagLink, 
    Aircraft.Email, Aircraft.IsSold, Aircraft.SoldDate, Aircraft.DateAdded, Aircraft.ExtendedDetails, 
    Aircraft.LastUpdateDate, Aircraft.ImageCount, Aircraft.ContactTelephone, AircraftModels.id, Advertisers.IsPremiumAdvertiser,
    Aircraft.Location, Advertisers.ContactTelephone As AdvertisersTelephone, Aircraft.EndDate, Aircraft.VideoLink,
    Aircraft.Contact, Advertisers.WASSalesEmail, Advertisers.WASSalesEmail2, Aircraft.PriceNumeric, 
    Aircraft.PriceQualifier, Aircraft.Currency, Aircraft.AircraftDescription
    FROM (((Aircraft 
    INNER JOIN Advertisers ON Aircraft.AdvertiserId = Advertisers.Id) 
    INNER JOIN AircraftModels ON Aircraft.AircraftModelId = AircraftModels.Id) 
    INNER JOIN AircraftManufacturers ON AircraftModels.ManufacturerId = AircraftManufacturers.Id) 
    INNER JOIN Locations ON Aircraft.LocationId = Locations.Id
    JOIN iter$simple_intlist_to_tbles(@ids) i ON AircraftModels.id = i.number
    WHERE (Aircraft.IsActive=1 AND Advertisers.IsActive=1 AND Aircraft.IsSold=0 AND (Aircraft.EndDate>=@Date OR Aircraft.EndDate Is Null) AND Locations.Id = @Location)
    OR (Aircraft.IsActive=1 AND Advertisers.IsActive=1 AND Aircraft.IsSold=1 AND Aircraft.SoldDate>=@Date2 AND Locations.Id = @Location)
    ORDER BY Advertisers.IsPremiumAdvertiser ASC, Aircraft.DateAdded DESC, Aircraft.ListPosition DESC, 
    Aircraft.LastUpdateDate, AircraftManufacturers.Name, AircraftModels.ModelName, Aircraft.ModelSuffix, 
    Aircraft.Id DESC
END
```

iter$simple_intlist_to_tbles(@ids) simple builds a table from the @ids input. This input comes in the form of a strings of id numbers seperated by a ',' eg ,1,,2,,3,,4, etc...

Now I need to replace the @Location with a string of location IDs formatted in this same fashion eg ,1,,2,,3,,4, etc....

So my problem is this... How do I adapt the above sql/ stored procedure so that the two 'WHERE' clauses which filter based on a single location, are now able to take multiple location IDs ??????

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, simply retrieve the values from iter$simple_intlist_to_tbles(@Location) in a subquery, and check for them with IN:

```
AND Locations.Id IN (SELECT * FROM iter$simple_intlist_to_tbles(@Location))
```

Your where clause is also more complex that it needs to be. There are identical AND requirements in each OR, so you can move them outside the OR. It simplifies to:

```
WHERE Aircraft.IsActive=1 
AND Advertisers.IsActive=1 
AND ((Aircraft.IsSold=0 AND (Aircraft.EndDate>=@Date OR Aircraft.EndDate Is Null))
  OR (Aircraft.IsSold=1 AND Aircraft.SoldDate>=@Date2))
AND Locations.Id IN (SELECT * FROM iter$simple_intlist_to_tbles(@Location))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a subquery like: 
FROM blah ... AND Locations.Id IN (SELECT number FROM iter$simple_intlist_to_tbles(@locations))